# How to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer programmatically

Tags: xcode, uigesturerecognizer

In my app, you can touch the screen and an editable `UITextField` appears on the screen. I want to be able to move these newly added `UITextFields` around the screen. I would also like to add a rotation gesture and a pinch gesture. This is very difficult to do right now, because every time the screen is tapped a new SubView is added (`UITextField`). Below is my coding:

```
- (IBAction)addText:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
   if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
   {       
        UITextField *newText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 205, 280, 128)];
        newText.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:newText];
        newText.text = @"phrase";
        [newText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:60]];
        newText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan= [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:newText action:nil];

        CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:newText];
        pan.view.center = CGPointMake(pan.view.center.x + translation.x, pan.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [pan setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to set up dependencies between gesture recognizers.  One way which seems useful here is the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method.  After you create the `pan` recognizer, add this:

```
[recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:pan];
```

Now the tap recognizer (in the `recognizer` variable) won't activate unless the pan recognizer has decided that the user is *not* panning.

Comment: Currently, I have just taken out the UITapGestureRecognizer haha. I decided to add the UITextFields from a UIBarButtonItem. Now, all my application does is add the UITextField but when I want to move it around on the screen, the entire UIView moves around.